# Renaming/reformatting saved searches

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Saved searches are currently displayed as (potentially) extremely long run-on sentences that are very hard to read. This makes it hard or impossible to identify them from the side box without having to click the gear icon.

[image: Extremely long run-on sentence in saved search]

We should be able to rename saved searches at the very least. Replace that ugly string with a nice input field. Additionally, categorization of each search parameter inside the modal would be extra nice. Really anything to clean this modal up.